# How to change default authorization mode for AppSync GraphQL API using amplify

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-cli

I have added AppSync GraphQL Api for my react application using amplify command `amplify add api` as mentioned [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js).

I chose the **API Key** as default authorization mode while creating GraphQL API. Now I want to change it to OpenID Connect.
I know I can change it using AWS console at AppSync > API-Name > Settings as shown in picture.
[image] 
But how can I change default authorization mode from API Key to OpenID Connect using **amplify**? Thanks